# How to configure a wcf service client to use both certificate and username credentials at the message level?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using a WCF that requires both username and certificate authentication at the message level. Is there a way to configure the client to use both certificate and username authentication either through code or through changing the app.config file?

Edit: The username and certificate credentials have to be on a single message to a single endpoint, not that one endpoint needs username credentials and another needs certificate authentication

This is my app.config file that was auto generated when I added the service reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService1" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="endpointaddress.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService"
                contract="EfmUserService.IEfmUserService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have different binding configuration for same binding type and associate the same binding to different endpoints depending on your needs.Try [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-bindings-for-wcf-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: I should have clarified more in my question. The requests that are being sent have to have both username and certificate credentials on them at the same time, and are going to a single endpoint. It isn't that there are two endpoints and one needs username while the other needs certificate authentication, sorry.

Comment: You need to use custom binding if you want both username (message level) and certificate (transport level) like this :  `<customBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding0">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Default" />
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>`